# How to get table definition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I need to get a table's definition.

Which command I can use to get this information. I tried to use `desc A.name;` but it didn't help.

Say a table was previously created using this DDL:

```
create table A
(
  id            NUMBER(9) not null,
  name          VARCHAR2(1024) not null,
  description   VARCHAR2(1024)
)
tablespace DATA01
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 128K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
    pctincrease 0
  );
```

How can I recreate this statement?

Comment: Did you tried to query in ALL_TABLES?

Comment: when you say "table schema like below", are you referring to the table structure/definition? Table Schema is not the same as table definition.Please clarify your question

Answer (score 3):

Use `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl`.

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (
  object_type     IN VARCHAR2,
  name            IN VARCHAR2,
  schema          IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  version         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'COMPATIBLE',
  model           IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'ORACLE',
  transform       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'DDL')
RETURN CLOB;
```

e.g.

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','A') from dual;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885

Answer (score 0):

You can use `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = (SELECT name from A WHERE ...)
ORDER BY column_id
```

I assume that `A` has a list of table names, so you want to select one of them for the query above, but I don't know what condition you want to use in `WHERE` clause, so I left that part for you.